# Only dynamically import module once rather than on every component instance in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react component that conditionally imports a module. The reason is if the module is imported normally at the top of the file, this breaks another project's webpack build that depends on this component because it cannot process the imported module.

I have solved this issue with es6 dynamic imports - however, the problem now is that every instance of the component re-imports the module. If I have 100 components on 1 page, it'll import that module 100 times, making it horribly inefficient and slowing page load times.

What would be the proper way to only import it once, then have the rest of all component instances reference that 1 dynamically imported module?

Here's my component:

```js
import React from "react"

export default class Link extends React.Component {
    state = {
        gatsbyLink: null
    }

    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        if (GLOBAL_FLAG) {
            import("gatsby").then(({ Link }) => {
                this.setState({
                    gatsbyLink: Link
                })
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { gatsbyLink } = this.state;
        const GatsbyLink = gatsbyLink ? gatsbyLink : "";

        ...

        return (<GatsbyLink {...}>...</GatsbyLink>)
    }
}
```

Comment: So code-splitting does not support your requirement?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Can you go into a bit more detail of how I can utilize code-splitting in this scenario?

Comment: the docs do a really good job of that: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#code-splitting

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure dynamically imported modules are cached. If they aren't you could export a promise that resolves a dynamically imported gatsby if the flag is set.
You will still have to import and call it in every component where you use gatsby, but it will not dynamically import the module every time.

```
const conditionallyResolveGatsby = () => {
   // You could reject as well
   return GLOBAL_FLAG ? import('gatsby') : Promise.resolve(); 
};

export default conditionallyResolveGatsby();
```

You could also try to use require.